# Problem in performing toggle functionality

Tags: google-smart-home

I have one device of type "Fan" .

While testing the toggle trait by using the synonym "Fan power, spin" . we found that google home is not producing accurate results.

After checking the google cloud function logs, we came to know it is performing OnOff trait functionality instead of performing toggles trait.

`**Below is payload of SYNC intent**:`

```
{
    'id': '...some device id...',
    name: {
                    defaultNames: ['Bedroom Fan'],
                    name: 'Bedroom Fan',
                    nicknames: ['Bedroom Fan']
                },
                willReportState: true,
attributes: {
 "availableToggles": [
                        {
                            "name": "FanPower",
                            "name_values": [
                                {
                                    "name_synonym": [
                                        "spin",
                                        "fan power
                                    ],
                                    "lang": "en"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "MoodLightPower",
                            "name_values": [
                                {
                                    "name_synonym": [
                                        "mood light",
                                        "mood light power"
                                    ],
                                    "lang": "en"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
}
}`
```

`
**Expected Result :** (en-US)

User command : Hey Google, switch/turn off fan power/spin on <device name>

Google Response : Sure, Turning off the fan power/spin on <device name>

**Actual Result** : (en-US)

User command : Hey Google, switch/turn off fan power/spin on <device name>

Google Response : Sure, Turning off the <device name>

I also tried giving the command of another toggle functionality(MoodLightPower) . It is working fine as expected . Facing the problem with FanPower/Spin.

Can anyone point out for any reference or any alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a bunch of different reasons why you are facing this issue. Firstly, the Natural Language Understanding system at our end is getting confused between Name and Name_Synonym. Secondly, try avoiding using device names in the toggle states. You can try using different name in the synonyms from the device name. Also, you try implementing your setup using modes. The way to trigger modes is different. You can find the sample execution [here](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/traits/modes?hl=en).